# how to not pick 3rd row in select Query

Tags: sql-server, group-by

i have a table (screenshot attached).when the Table has 3 or more records i don't want it it to pick 3rd row

SQL query:

```
  SELECT  POA.PurchaseOrder_AuthID, POA.Authorised,wc.Name ,POA.DateAuthorised,POA.DelayEscalationSentAt,AuthorisingContactID
     FROM  dbo.wsm_PurchaseOrder_Auth AS POA   
      INNER JOIN wsm_Contact AS WC ON POA.AuthorisingContactID=wc.ContactID  
     WHERE POA.PONumber = 'PO3841905_51_200908' order by  POA.PurchaseOrder_AuthID 
ASC
```

i can't use Group by as i need all the rows without aggregate function 
\
authorizing contact id can be different in 2nd and 3rd row (currently showing same in table)
[image: table Data]

Comment: SELECT TOP 2 POA....

Answer (score 2):

not wanting to pick the 3rd row using `ROW_NUMBER` window function

```
select * from
 (
   select field1,
    row_number() over(order by purchaseorder_authid) rn
   from table

 ) x
where  x.rn <> 3
```

Answer (score 0):

this question answered in Previous post but
for sql server after 2012 use this Code:

```
SELECT  *
FROM     Table 
ORDER BY OrdClm ASC 
OFFSET  2 ROWS 
FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY
```

and Previous version:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY OrdClm ) RowNr, * FROM Table ) t
WHERE RowNr=3
```